# Trading values internally in list

Tags: c#, list, compare

I'm working on a program in which a list of objects can either produce or consume power. Each element has either produced or consumed between 0 and 100 "power", represented as an integer.
Say element #1 in the list has an excess of 20 (meaning, produced 50, consumed 30 for instance), and #2 needs 15, #1 should transfer 15 to #2, and continue on in the list, until all elements have reached 0.
If the list as a whole has more/less than what is needed for the sum to be 0, it can take/give to an external integer.
I just have no idea how to go about doing this.
Each list-member has the following values:

```
public int Id { get; set; }
public int ProducedkW { get; set; }
public int ConsumedkW { get; set; }
public string Type { get; set; }
public int DifferencekW { get; set; }
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "transfer"? Would that mean increasing the ProducedkW, or are you talking about another property? It's not clear why Difference is independent of Produced/Consumed, either... It would help if you could give a simple example of "here's the data I want to start with, and here's the data I want after performing the operation".

Comment: Yeah exactly - increase/decrease the kW of the given member. The difference is something we used in a different part of the program - it doesn't really do anything in regards to this question.

Comment: Okay - a minimal but complete example would make it a lot easier to help you. (You might also want to consider modelling "excess from a previous step" as a separate property from "produced", to avoid losing information.)

Comment: So, that means you need an algorithm for your problem?

Comment: Tobias yeah, that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: You need to try every combination.  Usually I use a recursive method to go through the combinations.

Comment: Daisy I'd love an example, if that can help me understand how to solve this. When you say "modelling", what exactly do you mean? The entire program, when finished, will be connected to two different databases. One which has a record of all transactions between the objects, and one which keeps track of how much each member has at a given moment (represented by a list, in this example).

Comment: @jdweng Do you have an example of a method like this?

Comment: There are plenty of example of "c# finding all combinations" on web.